# SQL Dynamic Pivot group by error 1172

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, dynamic-pivot

I've been trying to get an SQL query to run on my database, but without much SQL knowledge and a database with multiple layers deep it's giving me headaches. I'm really close to what I want to achieve, I think it's just a minor detail I'm misunderstanding.

I've got a table of `orders` which I want to export nicely. I'm using dynamic pivots to generate a new column for each `purchasables.sku`, with in that column the `lineitems.qty` that belong to the `order`. I only want to show `orders` that belong to `users` where `usergroup.id` is `4`. I then want to show the field `content.field_customerReference` where `content.elementId` equals `orders.id`.

I've been using [this](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html) explanation and ended up with this query:

```
SET @@group_concat_max_len = 32000;
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(purchasables.sku = ''',
      purchasables.sku,
      ''', lineitems.qty, NULL)) AS ',
      CONCAT("'", purchasables.sku, "'")
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM craft_commerce_orders AS orders
JOIN craft_commerce_customers AS customers
  on customers.id = orders.customerId
JOIN craft_users AS users
  on users.id = customers.userId
JOIN craft_commerce_lineitems AS lineitems
    ON lineitems.orderId = orders.id
JOIN craft_commerce_purchasables AS purchasables
    ON purchasables.id = lineitems.purchasableId
JOIN craft_content AS content
    ON content.elementId = orders.id
JOIN craft_usergroups_users AS usergroup_users
    ON usergroup_users.userId = users.id
WHERE usergroup_users.groupId = 4
GROUP BY orders.id;

SET @sql = CONCAT(
    'SELECT 
        orders.dateCreated AS Datum,
        orders.id AS ID,
        users.firstName AS Gebruiker,
        content.field_customerReference AS Referentie,
        ', @sql, '
      FROM craft_commerce_orders AS orders
    JOIN craft_commerce_customers AS customers
        on customers.id = orders.customerId
    JOIN craft_users AS users
        on users.id = customers.userId
    JOIN craft_commerce_lineitems AS lineitems
        ON lineitems.orderId = orders.id
    JOIN craft_commerce_purchasables AS purchasables
        ON purchasables.id = lineitems.purchasableId
    JOIN craft_content AS content
        ON content.elementId = orders.id
    JOIN craft_usergroups_users AS usergroup_users
        ON usergroup_users.userId = users.id
    WHERE usergroup_users.groupId = 4
    GROUP BY orders.id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

This gives the error `1172 'Result consisted of more than one row'`. It works without `GROUP BY orders.id`, but then it combines all the results into a single row. I want each order to be a separate row. If I remove the dynamic pivot and fill in the `sku` manually, it works:

```
SELECT orders.dateCreated,
       orders.id,
       users.firstName,
       MAX(IF(purchasables.sku = '999992', lineitems.qty, NULL)) as '999992',
       MAX(IF(purchasables.sku = '9999991', lineitems.qty, NULL)) as '9999991',
       content.field_customerReference
FROM craft_commerce_orders AS orders
JOIN craft_commerce_customers AS customers
  on customers.id = orders.customerId
JOIN craft_users AS users
  on users.id = customers.userId
JOIN craft_commerce_lineitems AS lineitems
    ON lineitems.orderId = orders.id
JOIN craft_commerce_purchasables AS purchasables
    ON purchasables.id = lineitems.purchasableId
JOIN craft_content AS content
    ON content.elementId = orders.id
JOIN craft_usergroups_users AS usergroup_users
    ON usergroup_users.userId = users.id
WHERE usergroup_users.groupId = 4
GROUP BY orders.id
```

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: This is the query I'm running after Hogan's suggestion:

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT X.X) INTO @sql
FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
      CONCAT(
        'MAX(IF(purchasables.sku = ''',
        purchasables.sku,
        ''', lineitems.qty, NULL)) AS ''',
        purchasables.sku, '''' ) as X
  FROM craft_commerce_orders AS orders
  JOIN craft_commerce_customers AS customers on customers.id = orders.customerId
  JOIN craft_users AS users on users.id = customers.userId
  JOIN craft_commerce_lineitems AS lineitems ON lineitems.orderId = orders.id
  JOIN craft_commerce_purchasables AS purchasables ON purchasables.id = lineitems.purchasableId
  JOIN craft_content AS content ON content.elementId = orders.id
  JOIN craft_usergroups_users AS usergroup_users ON usergroup_users.userId = users.id
  WHERE usergroup_users.groupId = 4
) AS X;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Which gives the error

```
1064 you have an error in your sql syntax near 'MAX(IF(purchasables.sku = '999992', lineitems.qty, NULL)) AS '999992',MAX(IF(pur' at line 1
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I'm happy to go into that later today, but I thought that to fix my issue, knowledge of what the database looks like isn't necessary. I hoped that someone could tell me something like: "group by can't be used in combination with ..., try .... instead"

Answer (score 0):

Here I made a separate sub-query. You can test that by itself if it still gets an error -- I think the problem was the `"`s

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT X.X) INTO @sql
FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
      CONCAT(
        'MAX(IF(purchasables.sku = ''',
        purchasables.sku,
        ''', lineitems.qty, NULL)) AS ''',
        purchasables.sku, '''' ) as X
  FROM craft_commerce_orders AS orders
  JOIN craft_commerce_customers AS customers on customers.id = orders.customerId
  JOIN craft_users AS users on users.id = customers.userId
  JOIN craft_commerce_lineitems AS lineitems ON lineitems.orderId = orders.id
  JOIN craft_commerce_purchasables AS purchasables ON purchasables.id = lineitems.purchasableId
  JOIN craft_content AS content ON content.elementId = orders.id
  JOIN craft_usergroups_users AS usergroup_users ON usergroup_users.userId = users.id
  WHERE usergroup_users.groupId = 4
) AS X
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm not entirely sure what to do with this query. Can you explain it a bit more? Should I replace X.X with something?

Comment: I ran the query by adding some statements from my old query, but am getting this syntax error. `'MAX(IF(purchasables.sku = '999992', lineitems.qty, NULL)) AS '999992',MAX(IF(pur'` Any ideas?

Comment: @Sanderfish - I would need to see what query you are running but it sounds like your variable does not have enough space to store the result.

Comment: I've added the query and the error message to my original post. Also: there was nothing wrong with the `"` syntax in my original query – the error only starts to occur when I use `GROUP BY orders.id`

Comment: @Sanderfish -- yeah I see, you still need the 2nd statement from your original, my code only replaces the first query.  (The 2nd statement is the one that starts with "set")

Comment: Oh I see. It runs now, but as soon as I add `GROUP BY orders.id` to the 2nd statement it gives the 500 server error I had before.

Comment: @Sanderfish why are you adding that to the 2nd statement?  don't you want `group by orders.dateCreated, orders.id, users.firstName, content.field_customerReference`?  Or you need to have an aggregate function on those other fields.

Comment: Without `GROUP BY orders.id`, both our queries combine everything in a single row and add all `lineitems.qty` up for each SKU in that single row. I want each order to be on a new row, that's why I thought I should add `GROUP BY orders.id`, as the `id` is the only unique variable here. I tried doing `group by orders.dateCreated, orders.id, users.firstName, content.field_customerReference`, but that gives me the same 500 error as `GROUP BY order.id`.

Comment: I've no idea what that means -- what is the error message and what is the complete query you are using that gives you an error.